# Android Login button not calling onActivityResult or callback methods

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to implement the Facebook login button in my Android app, this is what I've done so far:

```
public class LoginFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private View mView;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private LoginButton mFBLoginButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
        mFBLoginButton = (LoginButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.login_facebook_button);
        mFBLoginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends","user_birthday","user_about_me","email");
        mFBLoginButton.setFragment(this);
        mFBLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "UserId: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "Operation Canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        });
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        getBaseActivity().displayToastMessage("Hey");
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I also added the Facebook activity and Id in the application manifest. The app runs fine and when I click the Login button it takes me to the Facebook dialog. The problem here is that none of the callback methods get executed i.e. onSuccess(), onCancel() and onError(). Also the onActivityResult() is not executed either. Please tell me if I missed something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long inspection, I found out that I set the noHistory for the activity holding the fragment to true. This prevented from going back to the activity again once the authentication was successful which led to onActivityResult() not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I too have this issue,But is solved by adding method in parent activities OnActivityResult function,to fragment method.

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    try {
        String fragmentSimpleName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (fragmentSimpleName.equals("Fragment1")){ 
            frag = (Fragment1) fragment;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    // facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (frag != null){
            frag.myCallBack(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```